# Enterprise Library 5.0 Exception Handler: How to remove sections from error message

Tags: enterprise-library, mongodb-.net-driver

I wrote up a custom MongoDB Listener with Entlib 5.0 as my Exception Handler in my web app. It works great except for the fact that it creates a document entry for every "line" below, including the empty lines:

```
----------------------------------------
Timestamp: 4/17/2012 4:13:50 PM
Message: HandlingInstanceID: c3c5f58a-89b3-4b64-b05d-3f72f998bab4
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred and was caught.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
04/17/2012 16:13:50
Type : System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source : MyCo.Webservices.TheCoolService
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : System.String TestExceptionHandling()
Stack Trace :    at Logging.TestExceptionHandling() in C:\tfs\Development\Source\MyCo.Webservices.TheCoolService\Logging\Logging.cs:line 55


----------------------------------------
```

What I'd like to do is throw most of this information into one document so as to not have 10 different documents for the same error. Even writing my own Exception formattter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664587(v=pandp.50).aspx) I still can't seem to get around the multiple calls to the customlistener.Write() method, each of which creates a new document in my mongodb collection.

My Entlib experience is limited, but I don't see how to get around it unless I write the whole ExceptionFormatter from scratch. Anybody have any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my problem. Turns out that I was missing the TraceData() method implementation on my listener. Once I told it what to do there, it handled the error message like a single WriteLine() call.